# Count unique quadrangles

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, computational-geometry, combinatorics

Given an planar undirected  graph with n points marked by integer number [1,2,..n]

The task is to find all the unique quadrangles, by "unique", we mean: if two quadrangles have all the four points be the same but only the relative order is different, then the two are treated as the "same" quadrangle. For example, [1,2,3,4] and [1,3,2,4] are the same quadrangle.

Input: The graph can be stored by whatever format you  prefer. Here we use adjacent matrix (for undirected graph, each physical edge is inputted once in the following description), the first two numbers in the 1st line is the vertex  number and edge number respectively. Then the following lines input each edge by each time.

Output: An M-by-4 matrix or list of arrays. M is the final unique quadrangle count you have found.

In the following undirected complete graph of five points:

```
5  10
1    4
1    2
1    3
1    5
2    3
2    4
2    5
3    4
3    5
4    5
```

There are only five unique quadrangles (ignore the relative order of the vertex sequence):

```
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     5
 1     2     4     5
 1     3     4     5
 2     3     4     5
```

I don't have a perfect solution now.

The following MATLAB solution can only find every unique quadrangle for Case-1, but failed in Case-2 , i.e. no quadrangle can be found.

```
%% Count Quadrangles

clc;

v = vertex(:,1);
t = vertex(:,2);
G = zeros( max(max(v),max(t)));
n = length(G);

% For muilt-edge graph , Build the matrix for graph:
for i = 1:length(v)
    G(v(i), t(i)) = G(v(i), t(i)) + 1; 
    G(t(i), v(i)) = G(v(i), t(i)); 
end
issymmetric(G)
max(max(G))

% For single edge graph, Build the matrix for graph:
% G(sub2ind(size(G),v, t))=1;
% G(sub2ind(size(G),t, v))=1; % fill the symmetric position

tic 

quad_cnt = 0; 
% G_ = graph(G);
quad_points = [];
%% O(N^3)
for i = 1:n
    for j = i+1:n
        if (j==i || G(i,j)==0)
            continue;
        end

        for k = j+1:n
            if ( k==i || k==j || (G(k,i)==0 && G(k,j) == 0) )
                continue;
            end  

            for p = k+1:n  

                if ( p==i || p==j || p==k || G(p,i)==0 || G(p,k) == 0)
                    continue;
                end 

                % otherwise, a quadrangle is ofund
                quad_cnt = quad_cnt+1; 
                % save the vertices
                quad_points(quad_cnt,:) = [i,j,k,p];
            end

        end                  
    end   
end
toc
% 0.1571 sec

quad_cnt

% output each triangle:
quad_points

%% O(deg*(V^2))
```

Test Cases
Edge inputs by using vertices index (Note: starting from "1" not "0"):

Case-1:
Input:

```
5   10
1   4
1   2
1   3
1   5
2   3
2   4
2   5
3   4
3   5
4   5
```

Output:

```
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     5
 1     2     4     5
 1     3     4     5
 2     3     4     5
```

Case-2:
Input:

```
8    8
1    3
2    3
1    4
2    4
1    8
2    5
3    6
4    7
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks. I deliberately "let" the index number become larger in the next iteration loop every time -- because if you don't do that, in some graph, repeated solutions will be found together. However, ironically, this way cannot handle case-2 as I listed above, where no solution can be found. You can drawn the graph for both the cases I listed and you will get the point.

Comment: Good point. I'll try again. For each vertex ('start'), for each pair of nodes connected to 'start' ('neighbors'), find a node connected to both 'neighbors' ('end'), where the node numbers for 'neighbors' and 'end' are all greater than the node number for 'start'.

Comment: I figure out a non-elegant way: 1. Find all (allowing non-unique) sequence of quadrangles,suppose the number is N;  2. Sort all the sequences, O(N log4) = O(N)  3. Detect and remove repeated sequence, Many tricks can be applied in this step, e.g. map [1,2,3,4] to 1234 and hash it.  But, I am still expecting anyone can provide a straightforward and elegant algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I have another approach to find the quadrangles. It's using the concept of DFS. Traverse the graph for all node to find the quadrangles for a certain depth. To remove duplicates, sort the quadrangles then remove the quadrangles or use hash table. My c++ implementation is given below:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

// if Edge[a][b] = 1, then there is an edge between node 'a' and 'b'
int Edge[100][100] = {0};

// to keep the list of quadrangles
// here 'set' is a data structure that keep unique elements
set< vector<int> > quadrangles;

// forbiddenNode[n] = 1, if this node 'n' is forbidden to visit
// forbiddenNode[n] = 0, if this node 'n' is not forbidden to visit
int forbiddenNode[100]={0};

// taken[n] = 1, if this node 'n' is taken in current Quadrangles
// taken[n] = 0, if this node 'n' is not taken in current Quadrangles
int taken[1000]={0};

void AddQuadrangle(vector<int> q) {
    sort(q.begin(), q.end());
    quadrangles.insert(q);
}

void findQuadrangles(int curNode, int depth, vector<int> &curQuadrangles, int numOfNodes) {
    if(depth == 0) {
        if( Edge[curNode][curQuadrangles[0]] == 1) {
            // found a quadrangle
            AddQuadrangle(curQuadrangles);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= numOfNodes; i++) {
        if(forbiddenNode[i] == 0 && taken[i] == 0 && Edge[curNode][i] == 1) {
            // take this node
            taken[i] = 1;
            // add this node to curQuadrangles in the back
            curQuadrangles.push_back(i);

            findQuadrangles(i, depth - 1, curQuadrangles, numOfNodes);

            // undo take this node
            taken[i] = 0;
            // remove this node to curQuadrangles from the back
            curQuadrangles.pop_back();

        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int numOfNodes, numOfEdge;

    // take input for number of nodes, edges
    scanf("%d %d", &numOfNodes, &numOfEdge);

    // take input for edges
    for(int i=0; i < numOfEdge; i++) {
        int x, y;
        scanf("%d %d",&x, &y);
        Edge[x][y] = 1;
        Edge[y][x] = 1;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= numOfNodes; i++) {
        vector<int> curQuadrangle;
        curQuadrangle.push_back(i);
        taken[i] = 1;

        findQuadrangles(i, 3, curQuadrangle, numOfNodes);

        // set this node as forbidden to include in any quadrangle
        forbiddenNode[i];
    }

    // print quadrangles
    for( set<vector<int> >::iterator it = quadrangles.begin(); it != quadrangles.end(); it++) {
        vector<int> q = *it;
        printf("%d %d %d %d\n",q[0], q[1], q[2], q[3]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will take a read for your code. I  am doubting that, there will be any "smart/elegant" way to fulfill my purpose WITHOUT using any special data structure like stack, hash-table (or hashmap) or queue,etc. Or in other words, avoiding the "deleting duplicates" process.

Comment: The following is my updated MATLAB code that works (you are welcome to test my code to see if it fails on any special graphs).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated MATLAB code that works (you are welcome to test my code to see if it fails on any special graphs):

```
clc;

v = vertex(:,1);
t = vertex(:,2);
G = zeros( max(max(v),max(t)));
n = length(G);

% For multi-edge graph , Build the matrix for graph:
for i = 1:length(v)
    G(v(i), t(i)) = G(v(i), t(i)) + 1; 
    G(t(i), v(i)) = G(v(i), t(i)); % comment here is input is bi-directional
end

quad_cnt = 0;  
quad_points = [];

for i = 1:n
    for j = i+1:n
        if (j==i || G(j,i)==0)
            continue;
        end

        for k = i+1:n
            if ( k==i || k==j || (G(k,i)==0 && G(k,j)==0))
                continue;
            end  


            if (G(k,i)~=0 && G(k,j)~=0)
                 for p = i+1:n 
                    if ( p==i || p==j || p==k) 
                          continue;
                    end

                    if (G(p,i)~=0 && G(p,j)~=0)||(G(p,i)~=0 && G(p,k)~=0)||(G(p,j)~=0 && G(p,k)~=0)
                        quad_cnt = quad_cnt+1; 
                        quad_points(quad_cnt,:) = [i,j,k,p];
                    end                                         
                 end   
            end

            if (G(k,i)==0 && G(k,j)~=0)
                for p = i+1:n 
                    if (p==i || p==j || p==k || G(p,k)==0 || G(p,i) == 0)
                          continue;
                    end 
                    quad_cnt = quad_cnt+1; 
                    quad_points(quad_cnt,:) = [i,j,k,p];  
                 end

            end

            if (G(k,i)~=0 && G(k,j)==0)
               for p = i+1:n 
                   if ( p==i || p==j || p==k || G(p,j)==0 || G(p,k) == 0)
                         continue;
                   end 
                   quad_cnt = quad_cnt+1; 
                   quad_points(quad_cnt,:) = [i,j,k,p];   
               end                
            end         
        end                  
    end   
end

% quad_cnt

% Remove repeat
% 1) sort
hash = [];
Base = max(max(v),max(t))+ 1;
for i =1: quad_cnt
    temp = sort(quad_points(i,:));
    quad_points(i,:) = temp;
    hash(i) = quad_points(i,1)*Base^3 + quad_points(i,2)*Base^2 + quad_points(i,3)*Base + quad_points(i,4);
end

% 2)  remove repeats
[C, ~, ~]  = unique(hash);

quad_cnt = length(C);
quad_cnt

quad_points = [];

for i = 1: quad_cnt
    num = C(i);
    digit = [];
    for k = 1:4
        digit(k) = mod(num, Base);
        num = fix(num/Base); % or use "floor()"
    end
    quad_points(i,:) = digit;
end 


% output each quadrangle:
quad_points;
```